# Error when installing Xcas on Ubuntu 18 -- Wrong version of mpfr

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apt, mpfr

I would like to ask a question about an installation error that I get when trying to install the [xcas](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/giac.html) software in Ubuntu 18.04. Although I managed to install the software via other methods than those described below in this post, I still would like to ask some questions about the error and related topics.

So, in the [downloads](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/install_en#packages) section for Linux debian/ubuntu in [xcas](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~parisse/giac.html)'s webpage, it says

> **Other**: Type the command `sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://www-fourier.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/~parisse/debian/ stable main"`. [...] Then run `sudo apt-get update`. Now you can install or upgrade by running `sudo apt-get install giac python-giacpy`.

I followed the instructions and I get this error from `apt-get`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 giac : Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.0) but it is not installable
```

Funnily enough, I have `mpfr` installed and up-to-date: I can print `mpfr`'s version with a C++ program that contains the line

```
cout << MPFR_VERSION_STRING << endl;
```

and the output is `4.0.1`.

Since I have a version of `mpfr` that is newer than `3.1.0`, I should not get that error, right? So, why do I get this error? Could there be something wrong with the installation of packages in my system? Maybe `mpfr` was not installed correctly? (it was installed from sources, following the instructions provided by the developers).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed `libmpfr4` from source, Apt and `dpkg` have no idea that it's installed, let alone which version.

A common hack is to use `equivs` to build a local pseudo-package to nominally satisfy a dependency which you have fulfilled by other means.

Of course, another way to solve this is to actually build a proper Debian package from the sources, and then install that. Just take care to use a version number which properly identifies your build as a local fork.

Comment: Ok. I feared it might be something related and now it's giving me problems. Thanks a lot.